# Rank value on stories

Tags: rally

When calling the Rally WSDL API I receive very large numbers for the "Rank" field, e.g. 500000011520, but I would like the get the rank in the backlog, e.g. #1.  Does anyone know how I can find or compute the rank in the backlog?

Comment: Did you end up finding a workaround for this problem?  I want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In REST, there are Ranking arguments for the create endpoint:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.39/hierarchicalrequirement/create?rankTo=TOP
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.39/hierarchicalrequirement/create?rankTo=BOTTOM
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.39/hierarchicalrequirement/create?rankAbove="/hierarchicalrequirement/12345678910"
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.39/hierarchicalrequirement/create?rankBelow="/hierarchicalrequirement/12345678910"

Unfortunately these are REST-only tools - Rally's SOAP API doesn't have analogous functionality. I'd encourage you to look at Rally's REST toolkits - they are definitely more flexible than Rally's SOAP.

REST Toolkits are outlined here:

http://developer.rallydev.com/help/rest-apis

Comment: even using the REST API for a QUERY [https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.39/hierarchicalrequirement/?query=(Project.Name=CIS)&rankTo=TOP&stylesheet=/slm/doc/webservice/browser.xsl&fetch=true] the "Rank" value is still the large number

Comment: You have to use the API endpoints to reliably Rank items in Rally. The Rank number is not meant to be end-user manipulated. Rally's 12.3 ranking ordinals are assigned workspace wide and follow a complex algorithm that is not at all transparent. Manipulating the number on an ad-hoc basis could result in unpredictable results - not recommended.

Comment: Is there another way?  I am trying to build a custom query that shows the 1.2.3... rank

Comment: The only way to get predictable 1...2...3 Rank ordinals as attributes on the objects would be to switch your entire workspace off of Drag'n'Drop ranking over to Manual Ranking.

Comment: I order them before trying to create. But note: newest User Story get's highest rank, newest Task gets lowest rank, so order carefully before creating.