# Rally WSAPI - RestApi: Can I set rank while creating multiple Items?

Tags: .net, api, rally

I have a .NET MVC 5 site lets users create templates of Features, with Epic Stories, that have User Stories, that have tasks, and also Stand-Alone User Stories with tasks.

They can then apply these Features giving it a new name for each feature in Rally via the Rally .Net RestAPI.

What I need to do is, create and rank these as they appear in my the user's template. What I have discovered so far is:

- For New Tasks: The latest Task's gets the **lowest** Rank
- For New User Stories: The latest Story get the **highest** Rank

You can see from this screenshot. The Id increments, but the rank behaves differently.

[image: screen shot]

So, for a dirty fix, I am sorting Tasks in opposite order of their respective User Stories so they go in right.

However, we're planning on adding the capability to drag/drop the order in the templates for anything, User Story, Task, etc. So, I will likely need to figure out a way create them in the right order... or reorder them after creation in a dirty but necessary workaround if this is not possible on creation. And it seems from some other articles I've read that there is no mechanism for controlling rank. The actual 'Rank' has been deprecated in the Rally WSAPI 2.0 and I am not clear on the other 'DragAndDropRank' documentation.

```
 toCreate["Name"] = UserStoryName;
 toCreate["Description"] = u.Description;
 toCreate["Owner"] = u.UserProfile.RallyReference;
 toCreate["PortfolioItem"] = Ref.GetRelativeRef(RallyFeatureObjectReference);
 toCreate["Project"] = u.RallyProjectId;
 toCreate["Estimate"] = u.EstimatedTime;
 toCreate["DragAndDropRank"] = counterEpic; // <-- I tried an int didn't do anything
 CreateResult createStandAloneUserStoryResult = restApi.Create("hierarchicalrequirement", toCreate);
```

I also saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382868/rank-value-on-stories) and it mentioned 'RankTo'=(Bottom/Top) but it didn't work for me:

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the rankAbove/rankBelow parameter for stories and taskIndexAbove/taskIndexBelow for tasks.

Unfortunately, the .NET api does not expose the ability to do this currently: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/issues/13

We just need to add overloads to the Create/Update methods on RallyRestApi to be able to accept a Request object, with which you could add that parameter:

```
createRequest.AddParameter("rankAbove", "/hierarchicalrequirement/1234");
```

I know the node.js and java toolkits support doing this currently, but that probably doesn't help you in the meantime since you're in the .NET stack...